# How to make several search requests at once with azure search REST API?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents) of the Azure API for search contains only single query elements. This is very expensive computationaly for multiple searches. How can I make several searches in a single request (Equivalent of 'msearch' in Elastic Search) ?

Answer (score 0):

By "expensive computationally" you mean on the Azure Search side, or on your side?

Perhaps running multiple searches in parallel would help?

_msearch is not supported by Azure Search API. You can create [user voice request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search). This would help us measure interest and prioritize this feature.